# Where to place and how to referance a folder with textfiles in Java project

Tags: java, android, text-files, directory

In my project i want to read data from several textfiles, therefore I have organized them into folders likte following:

1. textfiles

   - folder1

     - subfolder1

       - file.txt
     - subfolder2
   - folder2

     - subfolder3

My problem is that I don´t know where to put my folder or how to referance my textfiles. I have read [Where to put a textfile I want to use in eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850674/where-to-put-a-textfile-i-want-to-use-in-eclipse)  and have a setup looking like this:
Folder location:
workspace/porjectX/src/textfiles
Code:

```
FileInputStream fis= new FileInputStream("/textfiles/folder1/subfolder1/file.txt");
```

The result i get is a "FileNotFoundException"...

I have checked spelling, everything is lowercase and with no spaces. 
Any thoughts?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to make sure the folder testfiles is on your build path (Project->Properties->Java Build Path).
Then you can get the inputstream for the file the following way:

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("folder1/subfolder1/file.txt");
```

See also: [getResourceAsStream() vs FileInputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308188/getresourceasstream-vs-fileinputstream)