# FileNotFoundException from the Absolute path of a file (Even though the file is present).Why?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to access a file `test.gif` located at (`src/main/resources/test.gif` in Eclipse),from my program using the absolute path using the `ClassLoader`, in the following manner

```
String absPath=this.getClass().getResource("/test.gif").toString();
System.out.print(Path);// prints the absolute path /Users/Abby/Project/SubFolder/ProjectName/target/classes/test.gif - the file exists at the location.



 String relPath= "src/main/resources/test.gif";
```

However, accessing `absPath` causes a FileNotFoundException in my program whereas using `relPath` does not.

What exactly am I doing wrong? And how do I correctly access the file using the absolute path (via ClassLoader)

Comment: If this `Users/[username]/Project/SubFolder` is the correct absolute path, then this is missing a leading slash.

Comment: `Users/Abby/Project/SubFolder/ProjectName/target/classes/test.gif` is not an absolute path - you're missing, in the very least, a `/` in the beginning of it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where to put a textfile I want to use in eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850674/where-to-put-a-textfile-i-want-to-use-in-eclipse)

Comment: @Mureinik:Corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

You speak about relative path, yet the path you are testing with "/test.gif" starts with a /, why !
Please have a look at other response before adding a new question.
[Preferred way of loading resources in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3861989/preferred-way-of-loading-resources-in-java#answers-header)

Answer (score 0):

Use the URL and File classes:

```
    URL url = getClass().getResource("/test.gif");
    File file = new File(url.toURI();
    System.out.println(file).getCanonicalPath());
```

Also, getCanonicalPath() will return the absolute path for a file.
And you may want to check for null in case the resource is not found.